# Likelihood function for a Weibull model

Tags: self-study, censoring, weibull-distribution

I have an assignment for my course Microeconometrics. Currently I am stuck on the following question

> You are asked to help out with the statistics of a medical study. We are interested in the time spent alive, in months, after having developed a rare type of leukemia. The sample consists of patients who were diagnosed with the disease in December of 2014. However, the data only include spells of individuals who passed away by January
>   1st 2016. Moreover, we do not know the exact date at which patients developed the disease, only the date at which they received the diagnosis. Write down the likelihood function for a Weibull model without covariates for this setting. Carefully motivate the likelihood.

I started by defining the spell length as the length at which someone has leukemia. To obtain the likelihood function for a Weibull model for this setting, I believe that I need to identify the type of censoring here. Since we do not have information on the date at which they received the diagnosis, I believe that we deal with left-censoring. Also the data is only covered until January 1st 2016, thus there is also right-censoring. Do we therefore have interval-censoring?

Comment: Perhaps you could solve for the length of the disease in terms of what is known about its time of onset and time of death.